# Why can I hear audible feedback in my wired headphones when my computer is doing an intensive task?

Tags: audio

If I run an intensive Python program that trains an AI model, or run Handbrake encoding using GPU, I can hear a faint whirring or whizzing sound (and I am sure of it; it isn't just a psychological phenomenon or anything coming from the speakers output, I used OBS to verify this). What could this be? The sound lasts as long as the operation of Handbrake or PyCharm, when it is done the sound goes away.

I can hear it only with my headphones on, which are wired and connected to my computer case.

Is this bad?

Comment: If you google "audio feedback when high cpu" you'll find you are not alone. Maybe one of those links contains the answer?

Comment: people claim that a cheap dedicated sound card fixed the problem.

Comment: This probably just some electrical noise. It can be difficult to isolate audio circuits in a PC from interference  generated by other components. A separate sound card (as already noted) might help.

Comment: An unwanted *"faint whirring or whizzing sound"* should be called *noise* rather than *"feedback"*, which implies that there is an original sound source.